# Euro Truck Simulator 2 keeps saving game in Steam_Profiles folder instead of Profiles

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I need to use a tool called ***ets2sync_helper*** which will basically make my friends and me have the same jobs in game and thus make it easy to drive together. To make the tool read our profile, the game has to save its files in **My Documents - Euro Truck Simulator 2 - Profiles** folder. But my friends have their default game save folder set to **My Documents - Euro Truck Simulator 2 - Steam_Profiles** and then the sync tool says it cannot find any profiles in the game.

We have already tried disabling **Steam Cloud** option by right clicking on the game, then choosing **Properties** and then disabling the above mentioned option.

We've also given a try to making a new game profile and inside game unchecking the option ***Steam Cloud***.

Is there a way to force Euro Truck Simulator 2 to save game files to ***Profiles*** folder in ***My Documents*** instead of ***Steam_Profiles***?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty late, and this seems like a Superuser question, but links should be able to help if you've still not solved this. I'm not 100% sure whether it would be hard link, soft/symbolic link aka symlink, or junction. If you're going to try make sure you understand how to use them as they can ruin your game save data if mishandled.